# Office Mac 16 - Disable recent items list

Tags: ms-office, preferences

All **Office** applications offer a `Open Recent...` submenu (under `File` menu) that lists recent opened files.

Is there a way to **disable** `Open Recent...` or **set to zero** the number of listed files?

---

#### Why I want to disable `Open Recent...`:

The mentioned submenu is usefull. However the application attempts to access all listed recent files when `File` menu is selected (don't ask my why...)

If a recent file is stored on a unmounted disk image or network share the finder attempts to mount the volume.

Answer (score 1):

Setting to zero **Finder**'s menu recent items count (via `System Preferences` > `General`) also sets to zero all Office applications' `Open Recent...` items count.

---

Not a definitive solution but a viable workaround until Microsoft fixes the issue (assuming that is a bug that Office apps "touch" all files listed in `Open Recent...` when `File` menu is clicked)

Comment: Maybe worth trying to use the Shift + Command + P shortcut to open the *New from Template* window and then clicking on the Recent icon in the lefthand bar. This will bring up a whole heap of recent files and will show you their location. So you could look over them and right-click on any belonging to network drives etc and choosing the Remove from Recent option. Not sure if this will also remove it from the File > Open Recent menu, but might solve the issue. If not, then maybe using Shift + Command + P or the File > New from Template menu instead of the File > Open Recent menu is viable?

Comment: @Monomeeth I can manually remove a "Recent item" but as I open the file again, it's again in the recent files list. So everytime I open a file on a network share I would have to remember to remove it...